# I am not able to send mail in django

Tags: django, django-views, smtp, sendmail

THIS IS MY SETTINGS.PY FILE

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL= 'myyandexmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myyandexmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

This is my views.py file

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    name = request.POST['name']
    email =request.POST['email']
    message =request.POST['message']
    

    data = {
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'message': message
    }
    done_message = 'Your message has been sent. We will respond to you soon'

    try: 
        #send_mail(data['name'],data['message']+ '\n' ' from ' + 
        data['email'],'info@kahwart.com',['info@kahwart.com'],fail_silently=False)
        msg=EmailMessage(data['name'],data['message']+ '\n' ' from ' + 
        data['email'],'myyandexmail.com',['myyandexmail.com'])
        msg.send()
        return render(request,'artgallery/contact.html',{'message':done_message})
    except BadHeaderError:
        return render(request,'artgallery/contact.html',{'message':done_message})
```

This is working file on lcoal host but doesnot work on digital ocean.First it was showing
errors then i made changes to the code ..But it is not showing any errors now ..But it is not
sending mails either...when i click the submit message button it only gets refreshed..What should i do..

Comment: Remove `try/except` to see what's going on.

Comment: i removed try excpet sir but same is happening just refreshing the page...@Selcuk

Comment: Post your template code, are you sure your form is `POST`ing the data?

Comment: ye sir..I changed the template in return  to see if method was going POST..Yes it did changed the template..It is posting..Sir@Selcuk

Comment: <form id="contact" method="POST">

                              {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                      <fieldset>
                                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your name..." required="">

Comment: It is actually working but sending emails as spam @Selcuk

Comment: I would recommend to test by using the console backend, which prints the email to console instead sending it:  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

Comment: what do you mean by "sending email as spam"?  The emails appear in your spam folder? If yes, have you added the sender email adress ("from") to the email adress book of your email client?

Comment: Yes in spam folder @Selcuk

Comment: Yes sir i have added @Razenstein.U can check the code above. I am sending email to myself but locally I get email in inbox but on digital ocean I get emails in spam box.